# Matlab error , matrix dimensions dont agree

Tags: matlab, plot, dimensions

im trying to plot 2 figures, using fplot and plot functions, but for my plot (fig2) , i get an error and don't understand why;

Error using  / 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in bhpfilter (line 9)
    H = 3*g / ( (fo/f).^2 + 3*(fo/f)+3);

Error in @(f)bhpfilter(f,fo,g)

```
    function [H] = bhpfilter(f, fo, g)
    %freq finds the filter frequency response in V/V
    %fo is the cut off frequency, f is the input frequency and g is the filter
    %gain

    if fo <= 0 || g <=0 %error checking
        error('Inputs invalid');
    else
        H = 3*g / ( (fo/f).^2 + 3*(fo/f)+3);

    end

    fo=1200.;
    g=2.;

    H =@(f) bhpfilter(f,fo,g);
    H_1 = @(f) bhpfilter (f,fo,g)-0.8;

    figure (1);
    fplot(H,[0 2000]);
    title('Plot of H vs f using fplot');
    xlabel('Frequency (Hz)');
    ylabel('Filter frequency response (V/V)');

    fprintf('The value of f that gives a response of 0.8 is %f Hz\n',fzero (H_1, [0 2000])); %placed this line of code here so that it can be visible in command window , showing it works

    figure (2);
    plot([0:2000],H([0:2000])); % code will find individual values of H(1), H(2) etc.. but will not find H([0:200])
    title('Plot of H vs f using plot');
    xlabel('Frequency (Hz)');
    ylabel('Filter frequency response (V/V)');
```

Comment: the code above is by the way in 2 different .m files

Answer (score 0):

In the line `H = 3*g / ( (fo/f).^2 + 3*(fo/f)+3);` g and fo are scalars while f is a vector. For division MATLAB doesn't recognize the divide operator as element by element division when it is scalar/vector (it does for the other way around). You have to put:

```
H = 3*g ./ ( (fo./f).^2 + 3*(fo./f)+3);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: "The value of f that gives a response of 0.8 is 1092.820323 Hz"

I ran your code fine with that change.